# How to put two conditions in ANT Target?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

My need is to check two conditions in my ANT Target. If either of them is true the ant target must execute.

```
<target name="generateArtifacts" if="${generateABC}" or if="${generatePQR}">
...
/>
```

***The above syntax in WRONG.*** How to make it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's something simpler, but the following would do, I think:

```
<condition property="artifactsMustBeGenerated">
    <or>
        <isTrue value="${generateABC}"/>
        <isTrue value="${generatePQR}"/>
    </or>
</condition>

<target name="generateArtifacts" if="${artifactsMustBeGenerated}">
    ...
/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work unless the condition is inside a target and the "generateArtifacts" target depends on that target.